# Lost connection in war attack

Tags: clash-of-clans

I just finished deploying dragons in a clan war attack when the connection was lost.

Looking at the replay, I see that the server only registered deploying the first few dragons, which resulted in 0 stars.

Is there anything I can do about this? Doesn't the game know that the connection was lost?

Comment: Nope, once connection is lost, it's game over.  It happens.  I've had it happen to me before as well as many other members of my clan.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210268/results-of-getting-disconnected-while-attacking-a-village

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't really anything you can do about losing connection during an attack. As far as backend, it doesn't seem to recognize that you lost connection, and the attack continues with the troops you were able to deploy. So if you disconnect, then you are out of luck. The only steps you can take are towards prevention. Make sure you are on stable wifi, or are in a place where you have good service.

Comment: In general clash of clans seems to be unstable on wifi, I have been close to the router with stable wifi but still get connection lost in the game.

Comment: @Celeritas have you tried resetting your router? They can be finicky, but if your router can support stable internet CoC should run fine provided your device's wireless capabilities aren't damaged. I, as well as a number of people have no problem running CoC over wifi, provided our wifi is stable.

Answer (score 0):

There is sadly nothing you can do about this except maybe post it on their forum and brainstorm what would be a good idea to fix it and the only reason they have everything being done server side is so they don't have cheaters.

It happens to the best of us so it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is something you can do. In the past when Supercell had a support function I would have recommended reporting the issue. However now they don’t support individual cases, my recommendation is to stop playing such a poorly supported game. Not the answer you were looking for, but letting a game die that they don’t properly support is the way of the world.